# How to insert the same reactive value into each column of a single row of rhandsontable?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I'm trying to insert a reactive value, from a separate user input, into each column of a specified row of a table rendered using rhandsontable. Example code is posted at the bottom of this post. Immediately below is an image that best explains what I'm trying to do. Any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

[image]

In case repeating the same value in row 2 doesn't make sense to you, I'm slowly working my way towards of a series of calculations in rhandsontable that are based on one reactive value floating around when the more complete App is running.

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  useShinyjs(), 
  uiOutput("choices"),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(1,actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')),
    column(1,actionButton("delSeries","Delete",width = '70px')),
    column(3,hidden(uiOutput("delSeries2"))) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {uiTable(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
      hot_cols(
        colWidths = 80,
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if (instance.params && 0 === row || instance.params && 1 === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${value}`
           } else if (instance.params && 2 === row || instance.params && 3 === row) {
               td.innerHTML = `${Number.parseFloat(value*100)}%`
           }
           if(instance.params && 1 === row) {td.style.background = '#eff0f1'} // shade row 2 only
         }"
      ) %>%
    hot_row(c(2), readOnly = TRUE)  # makes row 2 non-editable
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$choices,{
    tmpTable <- uiTable()
    tmpTable[2,]<- as.numeric(input$choices)
    uiTable(tmpTable)
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI({
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) # I don't know how to insert a reactive value in 2nd position
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    uiTable(cbind(uiTable(), newCol))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delSeries3, {
    tmp <- uiTable()                                       
    delCol <- input$delSeries3                              
    tmp <- tmp[ , !(names(tmp) %in% delCol), drop = FALSE]  
    newNames <- sprintf("Series %d",seq(1:ncol(tmp)))       
    names(tmp) <- newNames                                  
    uiTable(tmp)                                         
  })

  observeEvent(input$delSeries, show("delSeries2"))
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, hide("delSeries2")) 
  
  output$delSeries2 <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput("delSeries3", 
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable)), 
                  selected = "",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  width = '110px')
      )

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace the `observeEvent(input$addSeries...)` in the OP with the following (see comment `# add`, only added this to make the code work as intended):

```
observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
    newCol[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices) # add
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    uiTable(cbind(uiTable(), newCol))
  })
```